# Is it possible to set which sound to stop while playing two sounds?

Tags: matlab, audio

I have this simple snippet that I have connected to a button, it shall play two sounds at the same time which is does:

```
[testSound1,Fs1] = audioread('testAudio1.wav');
sound(testSound1,Fs1);
[testSound2,Fs2] = audioread('testAudio2.wav');
sound(testSound2,Fs2);
```

The sound plays as intended when I press the button, but now I would also like to implement a stop-button as well. The problem is that this stop-button shall only stop the first audio `testAudio1.wav` while the second one shall still play. I have tried `clear sound` but this one stops both. I would need something like `stop(this)`. Could this be done somehow?

Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sound` will play out the entire signal by default and clearing will stop both at the same time.  Since you are using `audioread`, construct an [`audioplayer`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/audioplayer.html) object for both signals separately, then use the `play` method to play either sound.  You can also use the `stop` method to stop either one:

```
% Set up audioplayers for both sounds
sound1 = audioplayer(testSound1, Fs1);
sound2 = audioplayer(testSound2, Fs2);

% Play the sounds
play(sound1);
play(sound2);

% Do something...
% ...
% ...

% Stop the sounds
stop(sound1);
stop(sound2);
```

Note that the above is just an example.  To play a sound, use the `play` method and to stop a sound, use the `stop` method.  For your case, you only want to stop the first sound, so simply do `stop(sound1);` and not `stop(sound2);`.